Does the contraction mapping theorem ensure the uniqueness of the solution to ODE, or is another argument needed for it?
In "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (IntSM) by J. M. Lee and "Ordinary Differenial Equations and Dynamical Systems" (ODEDS) by Thomas C. Sideris there is a separate proof for the uniqueness of the ODE solution, whose existence is proved by showing that it is the fixed point of the contraction defined by the Picard iteration.
I don't understand why the uniqueness is not a consequence of the contraction mapping theorem. In an another book, also called, ODEDS by G. Teschl there is no such separate proof for the uniqueness although all these authors mentioned have (essentially) the same proof for the existence.
Any reason why one may doubt about the fixed point being the unique solution of the ODE ? The second author mentioned above writes the following:

The alert reader will have noticed that the solution constructed above is unique
within the metric space $X_\delta$, but it is not necessarily unique in $C^0(I_\delta, B_r)$. The next result ﬁlls in this gap.

He defines $X_\delta = C^0(I_\delta; B_r)$ as the set of continuous functions from $I_\delta$ to $B_r$. I don't know what he means with $C^0(I_\delta, B_r)$. Notice that the difference is ";" instead of ",".

I quickly read the pages in the book and I can't comprehend it either. It is quite clear that the fixed point argument gives uniqueness on the entire interval. If the solutions really separate at some point $t^*$, then you can just apply Picard-Lindelöf to that point to get a contradiction. Thm. 3.3 seems rather unnecessary (at least the uniqueness part). Could also be a typo, maybe the author(s) meant $C^0(I)$ for the entire existence interval $I$.

The strange thing is that J.M.Lee is well known author and explains stuff very well but he did say a word about it. No text between the existence and uniqueness theorems.

Yes, not carefully written

Correction to my previous comment: "he did not say a word about it"

Notice that the contraction mapping argument used to prove the existence theorem (Thm. D.3) only proves existence and uniqueness of the soluion on a small interval containing $t_0$. By contrast, the uniqueness theorem (Thm. D.4) proves that whenever you have a solution, regardless of how large or small its domain, the solution is unique. This strong form of uniqueness is crucial for proving the fundamental theorem on flows (Thm. 9.12).

@JackLee First thanks a lot for your response. But I'd ask whether this uniqueness follow from the existence part again as the first comment above suggests, i.e. by applying the contraction at the limit points of the solutions, where solutions may spread
